# If $f \circ g$ is continuous with $g$ continuos then is $f$ continuous?

Tags: calculus

If I composed $f$ and $g$, which is continuous, with also $g$ continuous  then is $f$ continuous?

I got just that $g$ is continuous in $f^{-1}$, but is it continuous in your domain?

Is like a counter direction of if $f$ and $g$ continuous, then $f \circ g$ continuous, but one is continuous and I want to know if the other have to be continuous.

Comment: "is it continuous in your domain", what do you mean by "your domain"?

Comment: Domain of the  function

Comment: You mean $g$ in its own domain?

Answer (score 9):

If $f = 0$ (which is continuous) and $g$ is arbitrary then $f \circ g = 0$ is continuous but $g$ need not be continuous.

If $g = 0$ (which is continuous) and $f$ is arbitrary then $f \circ g$ is the constant function $x \mapsto f(0)$ which is continuous.

Comment: This answer is missing details, counter example etc

Comment: @jimjim How does this answer the question?

Comment: Isn't the question asking if $f$ is continuous

Comment: Yeah the $f$ and $g$ are switched here, but this is still fine: if $g=0$ instead then $f\circ g$ is constant (and therefore continuous).

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a constant function and $f$ is arbitrary (maybe discontinuous) the function $f\circ g$ is constant (and thus continuous). So $f$  need not be continuous when $g$ and $f\circ g$ are.